# Updating projects in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created my website folder in Code Editor in Google Cloud where I put my code in. After that, I successfully deployed my website through command `gcloud app deploy`. Then, I modified some code in my .html in templates folder and I saved all of them! But when I go to my website, I still see something wrong that fixed before. I know that must use Google cloud command to update my projects. But I don't know the correct command. Could you help me?

Comment: you have to re-deploy your app. Just run gcloud app deploy again. Also be aware that if you are using cloud shell remember that you will lose everything that is not on $HOME folder, so watch out. If that is not enough go to the App Engine page and check that everything was deployed successfully

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not following the instructions on how to update a deployment on AppEnine. Follow the steps contained in [Updating a Deployment](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments).

If you are adding non existing resources you should also review [Adding Resources](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#policies_for_adding_resources)